# Python raw_input with while isn't working properly

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I am trying to get a character input from the user using raw_input() and see if this is Y or N. The code that is supposed to do the job is given below:

```
#
# Things I have done before
#
c = ""
while c.capitalize() != "Y" or c.capitalize() != "N":
    c = raw_input("\n\n If you wish to continue, press Y (or N to terminate) ")

if c.capitalize() == "N":
    system.exit("Stopped script......check your files if necessary\n\n");
else:
    #Other things to do
```

At the moment, I am repeatedly getting the prompt even when I press Y or N. Don't know what's wrong with it. I tried to use input() instead of raw_input() but I think I am using an older version of python (2x) and that's why need to use raw_input.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `while c.capitalize()!= 'N':`

Comment: this is really crazy and silly of me.....switching from one language to another is causing me a bit of a hickup...momentarily.... :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fault in your logic:

```
while c.capitalize() != "Y" or c.capitalize() != "N":
```

If I enter "Y", the first term is `False`, but the second one is `True`. `False or True` is `True`, and the while block is executed. Same thing if I enter "N". You have to use `and`:

```
while c.capitalize() != "Y" and c.capitalize() != "N":
```

Comment: ya nice...real slick!

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong:
if `c=='N'`, then the first part (`c!=Y`) is true, so you will loop (and conversely, if `c=='Y'`, c won't be equals to 'N')

Change to

```
while (c.capitalize() != "Y" and c.capitalize() != "N"):
```

or better:

```
while (c.capitalize() not in ['Y','N']):
```